# Logs are writing in console but not writing to log file

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, properties-file

Recently I migrated from log4j1.x to log4j2.x. I had replaced log4j.properties with log4j2.properties file. I am getting logs printed in my console but logs are not printing in sac.log file.

Pom File:

- log4j-jcl:2.17.1
- log4j-core:2.17.1
- log4j-api:2.17.1
- jackson-core:2.13.1
- jackson-annotations:2.13.1
- jackson-databind:2.13.1

Log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, RollingLog
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%C{0}.%M:(%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.RollingLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingLog.Threshold=TRACE
log4j.appender.RollingLog.File=SD/sac.log
log4j.appender.RollingLog.Append=true
log4j.appender.RollingLog.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingLog.layout=net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV1
log4j.appender.RollingLog.rolling.rollingPolicy = org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.RollingLog.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern = SD/sac/sac-{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
```

Log4j2.properties:

```
status = error
dest = err

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = trace

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern =%C{0}.%M:(%L) - %m%n

#File Appender for JSON log file.
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RALLog
appender.rolling.fileName = SD/sac.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = SD/sac/sac-{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = JsonLayout
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy

logger.rolling.name = SD
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RALLog

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

A.java

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class A {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(A.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` of your `logger.rolling` logger configuration is "SD", therefore only the logger "SD" and the loggers, whose name starts with "SD." will log to your file.

The name of the logger used in your `A` class is the fully qualified name of that class.

Comment: Logs file are generating now. Thanks!!

Comment: One more doubt, I want to print hostname and timestamp in my log file with "appender.rolling.layout.type = JsonLayout" not with PatternLayout. Could you please help me with the pattern I should here "appender.console.layout.pattern:".
I do use "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} source_host:${hostName}" for date and timestamp but timestamp is coming in epoch time and it is not printing any hostname.
I don't want epoch time, I want to print normal time format in the form of "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS". Could you please help me with the format.

Comment: `JsonLayout` does not have a `pattern` property. If you want to modify the format it uses switch to the more recent [JSON Layout Template](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html): it is the JSON equivalent of `PatternLayout`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used Json layout template in my project but I am getting the logs with few parameters missing. I have tried to mention those missing parameters in pattern itself but I guess that was not a right approach to get those parameters in my logs. Any suggestion on that?

Comment: You should post another question about this. BTW: if this answer solves your original problem, you should consider marking it as accepted (the checkmark sign beside the question).

Comment: Sure I will create a separate question. I mark it accepted. Sorry I didn't aware about that.